# Use SMTP to send email with different email address from authentication - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtp, smtplib

Hi I'm trying to use SMTP in python 3 to send an email, but with a different email address that I have authenticated. Is there a way I can do this? Below is my sample code. I know that there are some source working with gmail account, but couldn't find any for normal email.

```
import smtplib
import datetime
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

dateToday = datetime.date.today()

#Create a multipart for attachment
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'example2@example.com'
msg['To'] = 'example@example.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'Test'
msg.attach(MIMEText('This is a test message'))

part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
#Open a file for attachment
part.set_payload(open("Workbook1.xlsx",'rb').read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="Workbook1 (' + str(dateToday) + ').xlsx"')
msg.attach(part)

#Create user name and password for authentication
username = 'example1@example.com'
password = '1234'

smtp = smtplib.SMTP('mail.example.com', 11)
smtp.starttls()
smtp.login(username, password)
smtp.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())

print('Email successfully sent to: ' + msg['To'])
smtp.quit()
```

Comment: You'll need to have permission from the email server allowing you to send emails as someone else.  Another option is to use an email relay server where anyone in a group is allowed to send email.  Have you tried sending it as yourself?  Does that work?

Comment: Hey @dreamzboy, yes I did sending it as myself and it worked perfectly fine. But when I send as another email address, it did not work because I basically logged in as my email address. So I was wondering if there is a way where I can with another address.

Comment: Are you the person managing all the email accounts? If not, get permission from your administrator and have them set up to allow you to send the email on behalf of another email alias.